# signing api calls from frontend to backend

Tags: javascript, django, security, jwt

I am implementing a secure way for the frontend to communicate with the backend using a secret key. The backend is a sensitive service (mobile banking.)

First I was thinking JWT, but the token-based approach has two disadvantages:

a) the front-end has to obtain the token, this means it has to send some auth data to the back-end - and if the front-end can do this, anyone can do this.

b) even if there is some secure way of obtaining the token, anyone can fire up Chrome dev tools and use it while it's not expired.

So the alternative approach is to sign each request from a front-end with a secret key. The key is known to back-end and front-end the front-end is bundled and uglified so as to keep the key secret. We concatenate the request URL and its payload, encrypt them with a secret key and send the resulting hash in a header. The back-end gets the request, does the same encryption and compares the headers; if they are equal - it makes the request.

This leads me to three questions:

- Does this really mean that even if the request is sniffed it cannot be reproduced unless the url+payload is the same? Is there something i'm missing?
- Is there a JS library implementing this approach? (or maybe something for the backend too - I am using Django)
- Is there a better approach?

Comment: This is not a particularly secure approach: this is security by obfuscation.

Although the key is hidden in the front end through uglification, it's still there for someone to find if they try hard enough...

Comment: Rather than rolling your own solution consider using something tried and tested such as OAuth. There are libraries/toolkits available for the front end and backend (Django OAuth Toolkit)

Comment: JWTs do exactly what you are trying to recreate but in a much more secure way. If you secret is on the client side it is trivial to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Bundle as you want, if your security key which authorizes request is inside js i  will be able to un-uglify (beautify) and get it. Use SSL to encrypt connection and just use JWT ;)

http://jsbeautifier.org/

You will have to authorize user somehow anyways, so it means sending private data to establish the "session". Let it be username, email, password or some "secret" token.